# How to add ID field to the Table?

Tags: python, arcpy

I'm new in arcpy and need your help.
I want to do the next:

1. Create the table, where I store POLYGON data.
2. For each record, identify a unique ID.

I wrote the next code:

#### Create the Database

```
arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management("C:/Users/admin/CellRebell/ESRI_geo/dgb/dgb_1", "test_41.gdb")
```

#### Specify the table

```
result = arcpy.management.CreateFeatureclass("C:/Users/admin/CellRebell/ESRI_geo//dgb/dgb_1/test_41.gdb", 
    "esri_square", "POLYGON", spatial_reference=4326)
feature_class = result[0]
```

#### Add values to the table, where each value has ID and POLYGON value

```
count = 0
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(feature_class, ['OID@','SHAPE@']) as cursor:
    with open('_long_double3.txt', 'r') as long:
        for i in long:
                i_1, i_2 = i.split()
                with open('_short_double3.txt', 'r') as short:
                    for k in short:
                        k_1, k_2 = k.split()
                        coord = [[float(i_1),float(k_1)],[float(i_2),float(k_1)],[float(i_2),float(k_2)],[float(i_1),float(k_2)]]
                        count+=1
                        row = [count, coord]
                        cursor.insertRow(row)
del cursor
```

The script works and generates the table.
But at the table, I can not find the `ID` field.
It's the screen:
[image]

Where I made an error and how to generate `ID` field for the table?
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the ID field is missing? or is it possible that it is "hidden"?

Comment: You have this: `arcpy.da.InsertCursor(feature_class, ['OID@','SHAPE@'])` and then you do this: `row = [count, coord]`. You cannot set the `OID@` field manually, it is an auto-generated field.